# EXCEL : SUM many rows with condition

Tags: excel, sum, row, conditional-statements

I have 3 columns,
column A contain value that need to calculate later, and column B contain status ( 0 / score ), column C is going to create SUM function with range, but with condition from first score status to the second one.
for example : from this

```
1| point | status | SUM
2|------------------------
3|   3   | score  | <script here>
4|   2   | 0      | <script here>
5|   5   | 0      | <script here>
6|   9   | 0      | <script here>
7|   1   | score  | <script here>
8|   2   | 0      | <script here>
9|   3   | score  | <script here>
```

to this :

```
1| point | status | SUM
2|------------------------
3|   3   | score  | SUM(A3:A7)
4|   2   | 0      | 0
5|   5   | 0      | 0
6|   9   | 0      | 0
7|   1   | score  | SUM(A7:A9)
8|   2   | 0      | 0
9|   3   | score  | SUM(A9:xx)
```

for now, this is how i get it the first one, but don't know how to get the second one.

```
=IF(B3="score";
  SUM(
       ADDRESS(ROW(B3);1;4) :
       <dont know how to detecting rows below that have score value>;"0")
```

.

```
=IF(B3="score";SUM(ADDRESS(ROW(B3);1;4):<how>;"0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in C2 and copy down (the correct values will not be apparent till the formula is copied all the way down the data.)

```
=IF(B2=0,0,SUM(A2:$A$1040000)-SUM(C3:$C$1040000))
```

[image]